# Should I call getSystemService one time or each time when I need this service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

What is the best practice?
I can get service each time I need it

```
myServiceManager = (SomeAndroidManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SOME_ANDROID_SERVICE);
```

Or I can make member of the class mMyServiceManager, initialize it in onCreate() and use it when I need.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need get service each time you need it. You can use the second way.